# IIS worker process limit memory

Tags: c#, signalr

step1. I created a web service signalr. When I start web service execute the following command:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }
    public string ServerURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerURI"].ToString();
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        Task.Run(() => StartServer());
        //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        app.MapSignalR();

    }
    private void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException)
        {

            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Step2. I deploy web service on window server 2012

After successfully deployed issue I encountered was iss worker process memory limit

Comment: Does this run on the International Space Station, or do you mean IIS? What is the exact error message, and what did you find when you entered that message in your favorite web search engine?

Comment: Why are you using `WebApp.Start` (i.e. self-host) if you are hosting SignalR with IIS?

Comment: I'm creating a WPF client application and the web service is signalr. I need to create a web signal on a specified address 10.16.207.27. I used WebApp.Start (ie self-host). please tell me why I can not hosting SignalR with IIS.
how can I create signalr web service with address 10.16.207.27?